# date restrictions to be added to main method

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a method in my react-native-library that takes "from" and "to" Date as input.
I want to add a restriction in the below code.
**"to" Date should always be greater than "from" Date.**
How and where can i add this restriction??

```
const getData: getDataMethod = async (                //main method
  identifier,
  options
) => {
  const option = prepareInput(options)
  return option
}

const prepareInput = (options: InputOptions) => {        //prepareInput function
  const limit = options.limit ?? 0
  const ascending = options.ascending ?? true

  const from = dateToString(options.from)
  const to = dateToString(options.to)

  return { limit, ascending, from, to }
}

const dateToString = (date?: Date | null): string => {       //date to String function
  return date ? date.toISOString() : new Date(0).toISOString()
}

export type InputOptions = {      //type declaration
  from?: Date
  to?: Date
  limit?: Number
  ascending?: boolean
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `prepareInput` function you could have something like this

```js
  const fromDate = options.from
  const toDate = options.to
  
  
  let from = dateToString(options.from)
  let to = dateToString(options.to)
  
  if toDate < fromDate {
    from = dateToString(options.to)
    to = dateToString(options.from)
  }
```

In this way, the `toDate` will always be the greater one.
However, if this does not satisfy your needs, you'll need to put a validation outside of this, meaning that if your values come from textFields, you'll need to put that validation right there